# Twig: Submit form to path including the user-typed string

Tags: symfony, twig

So, the logic here is that I have a simple input text box, where the user enters a vehicle string,
and the form is submitted to vehicles/{vehicleString}

```
<div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search" action="{{  path('vehicles_search', {'vehicleName': vehicleString})  }}">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Audi, Toyota, ..." name="vehicleString">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I am getting the following message Variable "vehicleString" does not exist in ...twig, when I am trying to load the page that contains the search form.
I should note that the path /vehicles/{vehicleString} works fine, when I access it from the browser.
Any suggestions to work it around?

Comment: You should create a [form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. You want form to catch input value and generate some url path based on it? If so you are doing absolutely wrong things. You need to use JS instead.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I was just wondering if there is a workaround for that without using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: You want form to catch input value and generate some url path based on it? If so you are doing absolutely wrong things.

The problem is not in twig. You need JavaScript to make it work. I recommend you to use Angular for this purpose: you will have small amount of own JS code to make it work. But you also can use bare JavaScript or library like jQuery that can help you.

Comment: Hi Michael,
I was hoping in a workaround without using JS, but yes, JS and Angular in particular seems to be the solution here.

Comment: You can't have access to a variable that is not yet defined. Do you understand that user will edit your input-field only AFTER your Response will be generated and sent to him?

Comment: That makes absolutely sense.
Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have seen of late would be to submit the form to secondary action with the vehicleString a a $_GET variable and then redirect to you final url.

For example...

<kbd>Form</kbd>

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search"
        action="{{ path('vehicles_search_handler')  }}">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Audi, Toyota, ..." 
                name="vehicleString">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>vehicles_search_handler</kbd>

```
public function vehiclesSearchHandlerAction(Request $request)
{
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    $vehicleString = $request->query->get('vehicleString', 'none');
    // "none" just making sure a string is set, could be any default

    $url = $router->generate('vehicles_search', ['vehicleName' => vehicleString ]);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: It's not ideal but it does save on relying on any kind of javascript for a simple function.